# datepicker onClose issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

From researching on this site, I found a way to use 2 datepickers. If you pick a date on the first one, the second one will automatically show with the selected date as new minDate. You can see this in action on my test server here: http://www.zinius.nl/trips

The issue I'm having occurs in this situation:
Select the Check-in-date field, but don’t select a date and click somewhere else. You won’t be
able to get the Check-in-date field datepicker pop-up back up again until you refresh the entire page or first select the Check-out-date.

This is the code I am using:

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
showOn: 'both',
buttonImage: 'images/ico/calendar.png',
buttonImageOnly: true,
minDate: 0,
firstDay: 0,
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
changeMonth: false,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newMin );
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "show" );
}
});
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({

showOn: 'both',
buttonImage: 'images/ico/calendar.png',
buttonImageOnly: true,
minDate: '+1d',
changeMonth: false,
firstDay: 0,
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
}
});
```

I tried replacing the onClose with onSelect. This solves the issue, but when I select a date on datepicker1, datepicker2 appears and disappears in a flash.

Does anyone have a solution to get this working properly?

Thank you,
Guilliano

Comment: onClose check if minDate is defined and in case carry one with the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your `onClose` function on the first datePicker with

```
...,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
  var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  if(minDate){
    var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newMin );
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "show" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console, I can see this error being logged:

> Cannot call method 'getDate' of null

It means your statement:

```
var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
```

is causing the problem. What you can do is to first check if the `selectedDate` (passed to the `onClose` callback) is valid or not, before attempting to `getDate` on it.

```
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    if (selectedDate) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. Solved it with the conditional statement provided by Marco. Thanks for the help!